# Mstrweb getting newWindow is undefined

Tags: javascript, microstrategy

I am using mstrweb microstrateg, without any change I am getting the error like

bone-global.js?v=-1689619172:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: newWindow is not defined at microstrategy.submitForm (bone-global.js?v=-1689619172:1:291538) at microstrategy.loadIframeIdle (bone-global.js?v=-1689619172:1:293580) at mstrWeb:1072:45

Seems browser version issue? But facing the same issue on all browser now.

I am trying generate the mstrweb reporting on the url
Mstr/servlet/undefined

I am getting now undefined in the url

Comment: in url Mstr/servlet/undefined, can you check why you are getting undefined, Can you check the Iframe  is loaded correctly